# What can I assume for the voltage tolerance of commercial 12 VDC equipment?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, specifications

I am thinking about 12 V backup power supply options for my home networking equipment; these run from 12 VDC wall warts supplied with the equipment. The data sheets for such equipment typically say nothing about voltage tolerance. They often just say something like, "Use only the power supply that comes with this equipment. Use of any other power supply will void your warranty."

This [article](https://sites.google.com/a/clever4hire.com/special-articles/home/ac-dc-power-supplies---using-wall-warts) reports on tests of a variety of nominal 12V wall warts. Voltage outputs all varied to some extent depending on load. Generally, if the power supply was a linear type, output was 17-12 V (+40% -0% from 12 V), while if a switching type, output was 12.4-11.6 V (+/- 3% from 12 V).

I'll assume, for a start, that if I supply power within +/- 3% of 12 V, I'll be fine with any of equipment. I'm not so sure it would be OK if I hooked up a "12V" lead acid battery, which could be up to 13.8 V.

What is a reasonable limit for the safe tolerance on the voltage to my networking equipment? 5%? 10%? the range of an SLA battery?

I am particularly interested in hearing from 1) anyone who themself has seen a data sheet for networking equipment that does includes a voltage tolerance spec, or 2) someone with experience designing similar commercial equipment and knows what the voltage limits are.

Comment: We can't say anything in general as it is device specific and these infos, if available, are not general but device specific. Regulated power supplies could be well within 5%, and 13.8V is already +15%. If you are asking what can you assume in general, you really can't assume anything.

Comment: nothing really runs at 12v inside networking equipment, except maybe fans. chips run at 3.3v or lower, the ethernet interface needs 5v, etc. Anything with a tight voltage requirement would have it's own power supply or VRM inside the case or on the board. The only thing I would consider worrying about at 14v instead of 12.0v is a small bit (~25%) of extra heat if anything inside the box used a linear regulator for substantial loads, which is unlikely these days. The reg itself wouldn't mind, nor would a fan.

Comment: You can put a diode(s) in series from the battery to subtract a half volt per diode. 2 in series would turn 13.8v into 12.6v at about 90% efficiency. It would also turn 12.6 into 11.6, but it can help "center" margins around 12v. A buck+boost module could be slightly more efficient, but something substantially better than 90% could be $30 compared to $0.20 for the diodes. Also, a 12v SLA shouldn't be that high voltage, that's more like a car battery, where the alternator is quite aggressive compared to a stable and controlled mains-powered source.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the US - probably Canada as well - power supplies should be compliant with the ANSI C84.1 standard. 120v equipment, such as a wall wart, should be able to withstand voltages between -8.3% and +4.2% on a daily basis

---

[image: ANSI C84.1]

---

That being said, the power supplies likely keep a constant voltage on the DC side a lot more stable. Answers on [other forums](https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/575664-acceptable-voltage-range-for-12v-go-to-mounts/#:%7E:text=Standard%20design%20tolerance%20is%2012VDC,to%20prevent%20damaging%20your%20battery.) suggest a ±10% tolerance is common, though I personally would recommend a conservative ±3% tolerance for sensitive electronic equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The [SSI power spec](https://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/SSIF/2018-05-31/SSI%20PSDG%202008%20Version%201.2.1.pdf) lists the 12V spec at +/-5% with optional limits at +5/-3%.  That's for internal busses but 12V in to consumer equipment *should* be fine with that, especially since it's probably tempting to cut corners on the power supply and make the internal regulation slightly more robust.  That said, only the manufacturer will be able to give you a definitive answer and good luck trying to get one of e.g. Netgear's engineers on the phone.

13.8V straight from a battery is right out, especially since the voltage will drop below 12V as it is discharged.  You'll need to regulate it up and down to 12V as the battery changes voltage and also supply an automatic cutover etc etc.

Probably not the answer you were looking for but have you considered using a UPS?  Small ones to power your router, modem, etc are cheap (<$50) and if you were trying to power a server or anything more than a handful of watts, probably easier and cheaper in the long run vs. trying to roll your own.